# Modifying `FindMinimum` to work for noisy functions?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have an eigenvalue problem where I'm minimizing a function which is a bit noisy. `FindMinimum` seems to fail to work in this setting, can anyone see an alternative which works?

Below is an example which tries to minimize the norm of a $d\times d$ matrix valued function. Norm is computed approximately using power method. If I set `numPowerIterations` to something like $10$, which is required for higher $d$, `FindMinimum` takes forever. Can anyone see a way to make this work for higher values of $d$?

```
d = 3;
numPowerIterations = 2;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10 d, d}];
H = A\[Transpose] . A/Norm[A\[Transpose] . A];
Plot[Norm[(ii - x H)], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]

powerMethodNorm[x_] := (
   normalize[v_] := v/Sqrt@Total[v*v];
   step[v_] := (v - x H . v);
   evec = 
    Nest[step[normalize[#]] &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d], 
     numPowerIterations];
   Norm[evec]
   );
powerMethodNorm[1.5]
FindMinimum[powerMethodNorm[x], {x, 0, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

Background on math.SE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806469/solving-operatornameargmin-alpha-i-alpha-operatornamediag-h-2-alph)

Comment: your example works w/o problems for d~30. Could you post the  example taking forever ? I think normal user here won't read the background math so the more concrete example is better.

Comment: make numIterations and d much higher, ie 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled your code and used Bayesian Optimization.
I think,when dealing with noisy function,
 we should convert it into the `deterministic equivalent` or treat it as the `sampling problem` because getting the derivative is tough.

```
d = 1000;
numPowerIterations = 1000;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10 d, d}];
H = A\[Transpose] . A/Norm[A\[Transpose] . A];

nestStepNormalize = 
 Compile[{{x, _Real}, {v, _Real, 1}, {numitr, _Integer}},
  tmp = v;
  For[i = 1, i <= numitr, i++, tmp = tmp/Sqrt@Total[tmp*tmp];
   tmp = tmp - x H . tmp];
  
  tmp, {{tmp, _Real, 1}}]

powerMethodNorm = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
  evec = 
   nestStepNormalize[x, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d], numPowerIterations];
  Norm[evec],
  {{H, _Real, 2}, {evec, _Real, 1}}, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

Let's do [Bayesian Minimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BayesianMinimization.html)

```
bo = BayesianMinimization[powerMethodNorm, Interval[{0, 3}]]
bo["MinimumConfiguration"]
```

> 1.56589